# Как можно восстановить случайно удалённый класс в проекте?

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день, как можно восстановить случайно удалённый класс в проекте android studio ?

Comment: ctrl+Z по package-у попробуйте, мб спасет=)

Comment: @ Андроид Андроид забыл уточнить студия закрывалась и открывалась несколько раз.

Comment: <зануда>git/mercurial/svn</зануда>

Comment: так же само, как и любой другой файл.

Comment: Чтобы таких огорчений не происходило в дальнейшем, используйте какую то из систем контроля версий, например Git. Это позволит вам восстановить не только удаленные файлы, но и откатиться на прошлое состояние, если вдруг что то пошло не так, независимо от количества открытий\закрытий IDE/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Правой кнопкой в проекте по папке, где был файл, выбрать `Local History -> Show History`.
Там много чего можно откатить, даже если студия закрывалась.

Answer (score 5):

В андроид студио, как и в любой уважающей себя программе)), присутствует функция Undo. В верхней левой части, на панели нажмите кнопку с закругленной стрелочкой "назад" и ваш класс восстановится. Но если студия уже закрывалась, тогда считается, что изменения вступили в силу. При этом поискать удаленный файл можно при помощи LocalHistory - Show History открытой на папке, где был удален файл.