# Вернуть код после Pull в Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github

Я сделал Pull в Android Studio и нечаянно поставил Merge там где не было нужно. Я потерял написанные мною коды. До этого я не делал Пуш . Как я могу вернуть мои коды?

Comment: Студия вам поможет сама http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535642/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5/535647#535647

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое. Сделал. Помогло