# Деконвертация кода из Kotlin в Java

Tags: java, kotlin, конвертация

Пользуюсь IntelliJ Idea, решил по фану конвертировать свой код Java-код в Kotlin, дабы поглядеть как выглядят мои алгоритмы на новом языке. Но чуть позже с ужасом понял, что не знаю как обратить процесс конвертации... Чувствую себя нубом... Так как же конвертировать обратно??

Comment: как и любое другое изменение CTRL+Z

Comment: причина задуматься над использованием git'a в повседневной разработке

Comment: Ещё в IDEA есть *Local History*.

Comment: IDE удаляет .java файл и создает новый .kt, так что проблема банальна. Дубликат вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/535642/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B5/535647#535647